# Simple Active Directory and powershell combo , issues

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Well today i decided i want to have some fun with AD and PS so i bascially decided i want to write a script to access my dc and and its ou and sub ou's and grab all my windows servers deployed. however my scrip gives me the following error

FINDALL with 0 arguments , a referral was returned from the server. ... :(

Goal is : To find all server that are 2008 and up i.e 2012 .... which is why im using the version tag in computer set to 6.1 which is 2008 R2

here is my code::

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Versiont=6.1))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Windows,OU=Servers,OU=Alberta,OU=CA,OU=Shanes Home,dc=speed.speed.shane.net")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colProplist = "DNS Name"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objItem = $objResult.Properties; $objItem.name}
```

Thank You .

Comment: Just a tip: I would suggest using a module to simplify management of AD with Powershell. Do you have a 2008 R2+ Domain controller or 2003+ with Active Directory Web Services installed? If so, use the ActiveDirectory module in Windows Server 2008+ or RSAT. If not, try Quest ActiveRoles powershell module.

Comment: Hmmm i was actually reading on import Module Active Directory and then running a query such as this : 

Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem | 
>> Select Name, OperatingSystem | Format-Table -AutoSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tip: I would suggest using a module to simplify management of AD with Powershell. Do you have a 2008 R2+ Domain controller or 2003+ with Active Directory Web Services installed? If so, use the ActiveDirectory module in Windows Server 2008+ or RSAT. If not, try Quest ActiveRoles powershell module.

```
#Import ActiveDirectory module (will fail if it's not available on your server/computer)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#I prefer to store the original data first just in case you want to modify or export it later.
$results = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -ge "6.1" } -Property OperatingSystemVersion, OperatingSystemVersion

#Only use `Format-` to display data, never store it. So I split it to a separate line.
$results | Format-Table Name, OperatingSystem -AutoSize
```

If you want to limit your search to a specific OU, add `-SearchBase "OU=Windows,OU=Servers,OU=Alberta,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com"` to the end of the `Get-ADComputer` command.

Comment: hmmmm seems cool, i cant try this right now since my pc is being setup with win 8 :( ....but as soon as its back on :) i'll give it a shot :)